# React Hook useState value being reset to initial value

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, reset

I don't understand why but for example if the quantity is set to 5, as soon as it reaches the PayPal functions it is reset back to its initial value (1).

I also tried to print `Mounted` in `useEffect` to see if the component is initialized several times but everything seems to be fine.

Critical code below:

```
const PaypalCheckoutButton = (props) => {
  const { product } = props;
  const { user } = UserAuth();
  const [quantity, setQuantity] = useState(1);
  const [paidFor, setPaidFor] = useState(false);
  const [error, setError] = useState(null);
  const navigate = useNavigate();

  //quantity Increment/ Decrement in Hooks - start
  const handleDecrement = () => {
    if (quantity > 1) {
      setQuantity((prevCount) => prevCount - 1);
    }
  };
  const handleIncrement = () => {
    if (quantity < 10) {
      setQuantity((prevCount) => prevCount + 1);
    }
  };
  //quantity Increment/ Decrement in Hooks - end

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("Mounted");
  }, []);

  async function handleUser(orderID) {
    if (user) {
      const docRef = doc(db, "users", user.uid);

      console.log(quantity);
      const orderNumber = `order-${orderID}`;

      const docData = {
        [orderNumber]: {
          amount: quantity,
          paypalOrderID: orderID,
          destinations: product.name,
          price: product.price,
          Orderdate: new Date(),
        },
      };
      await setDoc(docRef, docData, { merge: true });
      console.log("User document was updated");
    } else {
      console.log("no user to update");
    }
  }

  const handleApprove = (orderID) => {
    //if response is success
    setPaidFor(true);
    //Refresh user's account or subscription status
    handleUser(orderID);

    navigate("/");
    if (paidFor) {
      //Display success messgae, model or redirect user to success page
      alert("Thank you for your purchase !");
    }
  };

  if (error) {
    //Display an error message, model or redirect user to error page
    alert(error);
  }

  return (
    <PayPalScriptProvider>
      <StyledSection>
        <PayPalButtons
          style={{
            layout: "horizontal",
            height: 48,
            tagline: false,
            shape: "pill",
          }}
          onClick={(data, actions) => {
            //Validate on button click, client or server side
            const NoSeatsLeft = false;

            if (NoSeatsLeft) {
              setError(
                "Unfortunately, there are no seats left for this specific trip."
              );
              return actions.reject();
            } else {
              return actions.resolve();
            }
          }}
          createOrder={(data, actions) => {
            return actions.order.create({
              purchase_units: [
                {
                  description: product.name,
                  amount: {
                    currency_code: "USD",
                    value: 250.0 * quantity,
                  },
                },
              ],
            });
          }}
          onApprove={async (data, actions) => {
            const order = await actions.order.capture();
            console.log("order", order);

            handleApprove(data.orderID);
          }}
          onCancel={() => {
            //Display the cancel message, model or redirect user to cancel page
          }}
          onError={(err) => {
            setError(err);
            console.log("PayPal error", err);
          }}
        />

        <div className="inputQuantity">
          <div className="buttons">
            <button
              type="button"
              onClick={handleDecrement}
              className="inputbutton"
            >
              -
            </button>
            <div className="quantity">{quantity}</div>
            <button
              type="button"
              onClick={handleIncrement}
              className="inputbutton"
            >
              +
            </button>
          </div>
          <span>Total: ${300 * quantity}</span>
        </div>
      </StyledSection>
    </PayPalScriptProvider>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, so I found a solution to the problem in case someone else gets stuck.
Taking out the part of the quantity to another component did not help.
It turns out that PayPal's built-in button initializes the page and therefore all `useState` parameters are initialized. To fix that problem I used `useRef`.
The `useRef` Hook allows you to persist values between renders.
It can be used to store a mutable value that does not cause a re-render when updated.

in the PaypalCheckoutButton component i have changed it to this:

```
  const currentAmount = useRef(1);

  useEffect(() => {
    currentAmount.current = quantity;
  }, [quantity]);
```

And it works great.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried to also set the type of `PayPalButtons` to `button`? I used to have this problem and this is how I solved it.

For example, add this `type="button"` where you use `PayPalButtons`:

```
<PayPalButtons
      style={{
        layout: "horizontal",
        height: 48,
        tagline: false,
        shape: "pill",
      }}
      type="button"
      onClick={(data, actions) => ............/>
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the response, I tried it now and it didn't help unfortunately.

Comment: Is there anything else that could be causing this?